# Enabling determinism flag on wasmer

Tags: rust, webassembly

I am new to Rust and am looking for a way to enable the deterministic execution flag property on the cranelift complier for my Rust project described here through Cargo.toml.
https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer/pull/709/files/6ca581279811aee9d26d77ed2b7372a6153fe3bf#

I would like the feature to stay enabled by default.
I tried enabling the feature on Cargo.toml like this way

```
wasmer-compiler-cranelift = { version = "2.0.0", default-features=false, features=["deterministic-execution"]}
```

But this doesn't seem to work as on doing cargo check I get an error which states that the compiler does not have this feature.

Comment: `deterministic-execution` has never been a feature of the `wasmer-compiler-cranelift` crate.  The pull request to which your question links shows the feature was added into the `runtime`, `runtime-core` and `singlepass-backend` crates, but I think there's been a big restructuring and those crates have since been deprecated.  I don't see a `deterministic-execution` feature in the superseding `wasmer` crate, nor from a cursory glance can I see any obvious issues documenting what happened.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to directly inhibit floating point operations through wasmer given these crates have been restructured.Thanks!